# copy active row From one sheet to another google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having trouble copying a single row to a second sheet with google sheets.

I am using Google script editor to send automated email updates which works fine. However I am now trying to log each update from specific columns. I need all the information in the row to move with the cell that is edited.

Each Row is a separate job-site and I will have up to 30 concurrent job-sites going on at one time. So the update may come in in cell "M3" or "M28"

What I am trying to do is capture only the row that is edited not the whole sheet. My current code is copying the whole sheet. I am drawing a blank on how to just define the single row as active and set it to a range.

Here is what I have. I am no java script programmer but searching this site has gotten me this far. Bare with the code is not perfect.

```
    function sendupdate() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
    var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
    var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
    var recipients = '';
    var message = '';
    var techname = '';
    var branchname = '';
    var city = '';
    var state = '';
    var technumber = '';

    if(cell.indexOf('M')!=-1){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('B'+     sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
    techname = sheet.getRange('N'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()  
    branchname = sheet.getRange('H'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
    city = sheet.getRange('J'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() 
    state = sheet.getRange('K'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() 
    recipients = "(emailaddress";
    var subject = ' Update: ' +techname + '  ' + message + '  ' + city + ' ' + branchname +' ' ;
    var body =  ': ' + message + ' Technician: « ' + techname + ' » New Update: « ' + cellvalue + ' » has been posted to the  Update Sheet Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: ' + row + '';
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Log')    
    var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
    target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);    
    sheet.getRange('A:P').copyTo(target_sheet.getRange('A'+(last_row+1)+':P'+(last_row+1)));
    }

    debugger
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I added which made it work

```
    var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Log')    
    var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
    var activeRow = sheet.getRange( row ,1, 1 ,16)
    target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);    
    activeRow.copyTo(target_sheet.getRange('A'+(last_row+1)+':P'+(last_row+1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the `Range` of the active row by calling [`getRange(row, column, numRows`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer))). You can then use that range to copy it to the other sheets